# Existed recipe to fix Eclipse debug certification bug does not work

Tags: android, eclipse

I was faced with the problem:

```
error generating final archive debug certificate expired on
```

but existed ricipes to fix it didn't work. What did I do ?

1. In C:/Windows/User//.android I deleted the debug.keystore file.
2. Clean the project
3. Rerun Eclipse

No results - anyway I see the subject problem.
Trying to fix it, I recreated debug.keystore, using the keytool in my JDK 1.7, copied new file to C:/Windows/User//.android, rerun Eclipse - no results.

Does this problem mean that my problem project and another projects were spoiled by this bug (feature)?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Android development tools are beyond frustration... I starting a bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about this particular error, but I've had similar errors that wouldn't seem to go away. If Eclipse really doesn't want to get rid of the error, you may have to reinstall it and start a new project and manually move your old project's java files and resources into it.

Good luck!

EDIT: Also, if you do this, make sure to not use the same workspace folder, as something may be screwed up there to.

Comment: This may be connected to an admin vs. standard users [configuration locking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214957/locking-is-not-possible-in-the-directory-c-eclipse-configuration-org-eclipse-os). I'll have to check that and report back. The main problem with re-installation is that Android's SDK+ADT tools have to be re-downloaded... and this takes way longer than mere unzipping the Eclipse package. +1 for now.

Comment: I re-installed Eclipse + ADT. **Didn't help**. The words "something" and "may" in your answer suggest that software development has transformed itself from science/engineering to mysticism... No one really knows *exactly* and *with certainty*. Amazing.

Comment: But re-installing Eclipse + ADT **+ using a brand new workspace** did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I just finished updating Android's SDK+ADT to the latest, and this solved the problem.

Turns out this has nothing to do with Eclipse (so re-installing Eclipse is not really the solution).

The funny thing is... there isn't any `debug.keystore` in `%USERPROFILE%/.android` anymore!

(but there is a new file `androidwin.cfg` in that directory.)

This Android development system is getting weirder by the second... Why install "time bombs" that force me to upgrade for no apparent reason? Let me plan & control **when** to perform an upgrade. I shouldn't be losing productivity hours in such an unplanned and unexpected manner.

**UPDATE:** No, updating Android's SDK+ADT to the latest **didn't** solve the problem. It only deferred it to the stage of running the built application on the test device. This is very frustrating.

**UPDATE:** Re-installing Eclipse, with a clean install of the latest ADT rev 16, **didn't** solve the problem either. It seems that the only way out is installing SDK from fresh? It's inconceivable that a fresh Eclipse + fresh ADT + fresh SDK will continue generating this error, so that's the only thing left to try.

**UPDATE:** Using a completely brand **new workspace** with the new Eclipse+ADT (but without re-installing a fresh SDK!) did the trick. It seems that the new ADT+SDK combination doesn't like legacy workspaces, or something got corrupted in those workspaces. I need to salvage them somehow because they are critical projects. I'll have to check whether copying the entire workspace to a temporary area, then importing all projects there will do the trick. This is so frustrating.

**UPDATE:** Success! Using a completely brand **new workspace** with the new Eclipse+ADT (but without re-installing a fresh SDK!), then **importing** all my existing projects did the trick. Bounty to be awarded to the one who suggested that. Oh, and the most important thing: **Do NOT use this environment on other than the Administrator's account!** (the account under which everything was installed).

Answer (score 0):

Delete your debug certificate under `~/.android/debug.keystore` on **Linux and Mac OS X**; the directory is something like `%USERPROFILE%/.androidon` **Windows**.

The Eclipse plugin should then generate a new certificate when you next try to build a debug package. You may need to clean and then build to generate the certificate.

Comment: That's exactly what the OP did before posting his question.

Answer (score -1):

After steps 1-3 just delete this error from problems (select it in "Problems" view and click "delete"). After this everything will be fine.

Comment: Tried that. Didn't help. The problem returns the moment you try to rebuild the project.