# After bumping up version of maven-assembly-plugin from 2.4 to 2.5, files within the assembly are now read-only

Tags: maven, readonly, maven-assembly-plugin

I am hoping that someone may be able to explain this change in behaviour of the maven-assembly-plugin w.r.t. file permissions.

This was causing our Eclipse-based application to fail to launch as it was unable to obtain locks on files because of [Locking is not possible in the directory C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214957/locking-is-not-possible-in-the-directory-c-eclipse-configuration-org-eclipse-os)

The original files I am bundling into the built assembly are not read only so I would not expect the files to suddenly become read-only in the zip file. I cannot find any information on changes that might have altered this behaviour; it seems like a regression to me but if it is intentional for whatever reason then users should have been informed about the change in behaviour in the announcement of the release of the 2.5 version of the plugin of in the changelog.

This might be related to the upgrade of the plexus-archiver transitive dependency rather than the upgrade of maven assembly itself.

BTW this is on Windows 7.

Edit: Simple example as requested:

POM configured with a maven-assembly-plugin configured thus,

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>binary.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                    <id>make-binary</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

referencing an assembly descriptor `binary.xml` that brings in some arbitrary files, in this case the `pom.xml` and the `binary.xml` of the build,

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

    <id>binary</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory></directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
            <includes><include>**</include></includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

</assembly>
```

Comment: Why don't you update to 2.5.2 instead of 2.5 ? Have you set fileMode/directoryMode correctly?

Comment: Yep 2.5.2 had the same problem. I shouldn't need to set fileMode unless I wanted to actually change the permissions, and it seems like this is for Unix-style permissions and I'm building this on Windows.

Comment: Can you show your pom file and the assembly descriptor may be via an example project ? (github?).

Comment: Edited my question to provide self-contained example :-)

Comment: Why don't you define the folder you like to include into the zip like `<directory>????</directory>` and define an output directory via `<outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>`?

Comment: Because that's irrelevant for the file attribute issue. This is a minimal example.